# What's the best way to convert binary data to character data?

Tags: java, encoding, binary, hex, base64

I want convert a File(.jpg image file) into a txt file(ASCII code)

now, I had two plans, convert file bytes to Hex,and to Base64

```
  File file=new File("D:/temp/1.jpg");
  byte[] bytes=getBytesFromFile(file);
  System.out.println("bytes:"+bytes.length);//bytes:9006
  String hex=HexUtil.asHex(bytes);
  String base64=Base64.encode(bytes);
  System.out.println("hex:"+hex.length());//hex:18012
  System.out.println("base64:"+base64.length());//base64:12165
```

I think Base64 is better,because send 12165 less than hex string.

I want to know,any other good idea to do it?

thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Your question can be rephreased as "What's the best way to convert binary data to character data?". Yes, usually Base64 is used for this.

Comment: thanks ,i fixed my title,my english is suck,sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base64 is more or less the standard way of transferring binary information as string. So yes, you are doing it correct. Wikipedia:

> Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs be stored and transferred over media that are designed to deal with textual data

In my practice I've used it to transfer attached documents when sending them via web services. (This was regulated by the government (the project was about e-government))